# How does Java evaluate this type of code in the if statement?

Tags: java

This does two things. It adds an item to a list and **at the same time**, also evaluates if the item exists in the list, and presents a message. Is this some sort of a real world practice or should I consider it as a hack? How does it work at the back end.

```
if(!list.add(value)) {
   //message
}
```

I would have done something like this though.

```
boolean res = list.add(value);
    if (!res) {
//print out a message
}
```

Comment: Will that matter? I mean, does list type affect the evaluation?

Comment: Doesn't matter much in this case. I just wanted to say that you should always add such information to your question. This avoids keeping people wondering what is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a hack; `List.add()` returns a `boolean` (i.e. whether the operation was successful or not).

However, many would consider the code in your snippet to be an unpleasant coding style (i.e. hiding side-effects in what superficially appears to be a conditional check).  Splitting this into two lines would be the preferred approach:

```
final boolean success = list.add(value);
if (!success) {
    // message
}
```

(Of course, the price here is increased verbosity.)

Comment: Well, verbosity is generally preferred :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to existing answers.

[List#add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29) will always return true, since it is unbounded and can contain duplicates. [Set#add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29) may return false, if you are adding an element that is already in the set. Therefore you can use result of [Collection#add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add%28E%29) method to check if an element you added changed the collection.